# Pandas and scikit-learn: KeyError: [....] not in index

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I do not understand why do I get the error `KeyError: '[ 1351  1352  1353 ... 13500 13501 13502] not in index'` when I run this code:

```
cv = KFold(n_splits=10)

for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    f_train_X, f_valid_X = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    f_train_y, f_valid_y = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

I use `X` (a Pandas dataframe) to split I `cv.split(X)`.

```
X.shape
y.shape
Out: (13503, 17)
Out: (13503,)
```

Answer (score 29):

***The problem is the way you are trying to index the `X` using `X[train_index]`.*
*You need to use `.loc` or `.iloc` since you have `pandas` dataframe.***

---

#### Use this

```
cv = KFold(n_splits=10)

for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    f_train_X, f_valid_X = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    f_train_y, f_valid_y = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

#### 1st way: Example using `iloc`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df[[1,2]]
#KeyError: '[1 2] not in index'

df.iloc[[1,2]]
#    A   B   C   D
#1  25  97  78  74
#2   6  84  16  21
```

#### 2nd way: Example by converting pandas to numpy in advance

```
df = df.values

#now this should work fine
df[[1,2]]
#array([[25, 97, 78, 74],
#      [ 6, 84, 16, 21]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Does it mean that X[train_index] requires numpy array?

Comment: The default indexing of scikit-learn functions are expecting numpy arrays. Use .iloc or use `X = X.values` in advance. Please consider accepting my answer