# i have a simple Error from my k-fold cross validation code for a logistic regression model Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science, google-colaboratory

i have this error below from my code for a K-Fold cross validation

```
"None of [Int64Index([      0,       1,       3,       4,       5,       6,       7,\n                  8,       9,      10,\n            ...\n            1048565, 1048566, 1048567, 1048568, 1048569, 1048570, 1048571,\n            1048572, 1048573, 1048574],\n           dtype='int64', length=943717)] are in the [columns]"
```

the model is logistic regression model and i need to evaluate it using K-fold
however if you have another code in python i would be thankful

this is my code

```
y3_data = data['DEATH']
    #dependant variable y_data:
x3_data = df14
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=0)
x3_resampled,y3_resampled = rus.fit_resample(x3_data,y3_data)




    #training and test sample :
x3_training_data, x3_test_data, y3_training_data, y3_test_data = train_test_split(x3_data, y3_data, test_size = 0.3)

    # Estimation result:
logit_model=sm.Logit(y3_training_data,x3_training_data)
result3=logit_model.fit()
print(result3.summary2())

    # Model Evaluation  :
logreg=LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x3_training_data,y3_training_data)
y_pred=logreg.predict(x3_test_data)
print('Logistic regression model accuracy:{:.2f}'.format(logreg.score(x3_test_data,y3_test_data)))
print("Logistic Regression F1 Score :",f1_score(y3_test_data,logreg.predict(x3_test_data),average=None))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y3_test_data, logreg.predict(x3_test_data)), annot=True, fmt=".0f")
plt.title("Logistic Regression Confusion Matrix",fontsize=18, color="red");

num_splits = 10 
kfold = StratifiedKFold(num_splits, shuffle= True, random_state = 1)
train_accs, test_accs = [], []  #create empty lists to store accurcy values
for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(x3_data, y3_data):  #Generate indices to split data into training and test set.
    x3_train, x3_test = x3_data[train_index], x3_data[test_index]
    y3_train, y3_test = y3_data[train_index], y3_data[test_index]
  
    logreg.fit(x3_train, y3_train)
    y3_pred_train = logreg.predict(x3_train)
    y3_pred_test = logreg.predict(x3_test)
    
    train_accs.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y3_train, y3_pred_train) * 100)
    test_accs.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y3_test, y3_pred_test) * 100)

ave_train_acc = 0
ave_test_acc = 0

print("\t","Training_Acc","\t","\t", "Testing_Acc")

for i in range(num_splits):
    print(i,"\t", train_accs[i],"\t", test_accs[i])
    
    ave_train_acc+= train_accs[i]/num_splits
    ave_test_acc+= test_accs[i]/num_splits
    
print("Av", "\t", ave_train_acc,"\t", ave_test_acc)
```

the error is only on the k fold part

and i want the output to be like this one below

```
     Training_Acc        Testing_Acc
0    76.0586319218241    75.32467532467533
1    75.2442996742671    74.67532467532467
2    73.9413680781759    81.16883116883116
3    77.72357723577235   71.89542483660131
4    76.7479674796748    73.20261437908496
Av   75.94316887794285   75.25337407690348
```

PLEASE help

THIS IS the full error trace track

```
RF Regression F1 Score : [0.96507625 0.47731195]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-955883a0e9f9> in <module>
     62 train_accs, test_accs = [], []  #create empty lists to store accurcy values
     63 for train_index, test_index in kfold.split(x_data, y_data):  #Generate indices to split data into training and test set.
---> 64     x_train_data, x_test_data = x_data[train_index], x_data[test_index]
     65     y_train, y_test = y_data[train_index], y_data[test_index]
     66 

    2 frames
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
       1372                 if use_interval_msg:
       1373                     key = list(key)
    -> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
       1375 
       1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
    
    KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([      0,       1,       3,       4,       5,       6,       7,\n                  8,       9,      10,\n            ...\n            1048564, 1048565, 1048566, 1048567, 1048568, 1048569, 1048570,\n            1048572, 1048573, 1048574],\n           dtype='int64', length=838860)] are in the [columns]"
```

new error

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

4 frames

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:
```

Comment: Could you please provide the trace?

Comment: i am not sure i know what trace is however, y3_data is the death variable 0 for alive and 1 for dead, x3_data are my categorical variable the are all have binary output for example Diabetes 0 for yes 1 for no and so on i have around 6 variables in x3_data that have a significant P value with y3_data

Comment: i hope i am clear about it help please

Comment: the error is in this part

Comment: x3_training_data, x3_test_data = x3_data[train_index], x3_data[test_index]

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I am asking you to paste the error traceback to your question - https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-traceback/amp/

Comment: hi , it is okay i posted the full trace error on the question thank you

Comment: Replace your line - 
`x_train_data, x_test_data = x_data[train_index], x_data[test_index]` with `x_train_data, x_test_data = x_data[0].values[train_index], x_data[0].values[test_index]`

Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949390/none-of-int64index-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-2

Your data is in the form of Pandas dataframe and you seem to be indexing it assuming it to be a numpy array

Comment: it has an error

Comment: Could you print out the error? Thanks!

Comment: i added the new error in the post thank u

Comment: This doesn't seem like the entire traceback. I don't see where the error originated from. Could you please update the traceback?

Comment: hi i update the trace and it is still the same help

Comment: It still don't see where the error originated from. The error has to come from some line of your code. 
Did you paste the entire trace? Perhaps something is missing.

Comment: Also, if you copy a bit of your data or create a minimal working example, I could help better :)

Comment: @desert_ranger Your earlier suggested change probably shouldn't have the `[0]` in it; the cited question was dealing with a _tuple of_ frames.